# Can we retrieve JWT token for a current logged in user in grails

Tags: spring, grails, jwt, token

I am building a web application in Grails with Spring Security REST. I wanted to know if we can retrieve the token in a service method for a logged in user? I can see that there are just 3 methods defined in the TokenStorageService which can't do what is needed. Any help will be appreciated.

Grails Version 3.3.5
Spring Security Core 3.2.3
Spring Security Rest 2.0.0.RC1

Comment: The token would generally be included in the `Authorization` request header.  Why do you want to retrieve it?

Comment: I need to pass that token to another application for validation. I guess I came around with a solution. I created a dedicated user in my grails app and call the login API to get a token. This token is passed to the other application and is validated by it.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a way of doing this? I want to do the same sort of handoff of a token.